# How many five digit numbers can be formed from the integers 1,2,..,9 with one digit appearing at max thrice?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The problem is in the title of the question, repeated below:

> How many five digit numbers can be formed from the integers 1,2,..,9 with one digit appearing at max thrice?

I have two solutions as below but they give different counts. Does solution 1 counts some numbers multiple times? Or does solution 2 miss to count certain numbers? I am not able to find the reason for the gap between two counts.

> **Solution 1**
>
> It should be the sum of following:
>   (1) No digit repeating: ${}^9P_5$
>   (2) One digit repeating twice: $9\times {}^5C_2\times 8\times 7\times 6$
>   (3) Two digits repeating twice: $9\times 8\times {}^5C_2\times {}^3C_2\times 7$
>   (4) One repeating thrice and others not repeating: $9\times {}^5C_3\times 8\times 7$
>   (5) One repeating thrice and other twice: $9\times {}^5C_3\times 8$
>   Sum of (1) to (5) is $66240$

---

> **Solution 2**
>
> Total numbers $= 9^5$
>   Unwanted numbers:
>
> - All same digits = 9 ways (11111,22222... 99999)
> - 4 digits same $= 9 \times ({}^5C_4 \times 8)$
>     For example,
>     four 1's: ${}^5C_4 \times 8$ ways,
>     four 2's: again ${}^5C_4 \times 8$ ways
>     Hence for 9 such cases $9 \times ({}^5C_4 \times 8)$ ways
>
> Hence Ans $= 9^5 - (72 * {}^5C_4) - 9=49968$

Comment: I don't think the rules are clear.  Do the non-repeat numbers occur uniquely? That is, is $11122$ a good example or not?

Comment: I see you using binomial coefficients and such in your solutions, but it is not clear whether or not you actually realize what they represent or why you are wanting to use them.  In your solution2 for instance... you used $\binom{9}{4}$.  Why $9$?  Why $4$?  Think about what it is we are choosing here... digits?  Or **positions**?  And if positions, how many were there to choose from?  Not nine, I can tell you that.

Comment: As for solution1, you made a mistake in case3.  After having finished arranging, you have no way of distinguishing which was the "first" number used for a pair that you selected and which was the second.  You should be able to tell very quickly that a mistake was made in solution1 since, as you correctly noted, there are $9^5=59049$ possible numbers if we ignore the condition on no number occurring more than 3 times each, but $66240>59049$, so that can't be the answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry it was ${}^5C_4$ instead of ${}^9C_4$

Comment: Yes, and with that change (*and once your final arithmetic reflects this change as well*) it becomes correct.  As for solution1, it was close, but as previously mentioned, you doublecounted in case3.  The numbers used for pairs should have been selected simultaneously, not in sequence.  Dividing your total for case3 by $2$ will correct that approach, both giving the correct final total of $58680$

Comment: How to perfect counting skills so that I can avoid such mistakes? Just curious do you make no mistake always. That is, given any such problem, are you able to always come up with right answer? If yes, how to be like that?

Comment: Also, just to generalize, if there were $k$ such digits with same number of occurrences, I will have to divide case 3 by $k!$ right?

Comment: Experience is a big part of it... I've seen most of the possible mistakes that students make with problems like these at this point and have as a result learned how to avoid them.  A good rule of thumb is that you should recognize that we are technically behind the scenes trying to define a bijection between our sequences of choices and an outcome that we wanted to count and that such bijections should be reversible.  So, look at an outcome and check to make sure that exactly one sequence of choices led to it.  If multiple sequences or no sequences of choices lead to it, you've got a problem.

Comment: For *two digits repeating twice* you have 15120. I get 7560: 9 for the singleton, 5 for its position, 8·7 for the paired digits, 3 for which of the last three paired digits matches the first paired digit.